# No way to compile smart pointer with mingw-w64

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, mingw-w64

I am using lasted mingw w64 compiler (from April 2014, with g++ 4.9.0), and I am unable to compile smart pointers (including `<memory>` header ), either with `-std=c++0x` or `gnu0x`. I get always same error:

```
error: 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
```

I was told that lastest gcc was able to compile that. But this don't seem to be my case. I am missing anything?

Comment: Tried `-std=c++11` also?

Comment: That error message is strange, looks like it's finding a non-template `std::shared_ptr`. Could you provide a minimal example of code that produces that error? (`shared_ptr` has been available for a while, since GCC 4.5 series at least.)

Comment: I am compiling with this command : "g++ -std=c++11 -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o build/main.o -c src/main.cpp". Is there some mistake there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `-ansi` compiler flag. For C++, it is equivalent to `-std=c++98`.
It comes after `-std=c++11` and is overriding it. `std::shared_ptr` did not exist in C++98